# query about xml parsing

Tags: iphone

i just want to knw,is there any boundations in xml parsing with characters

like can we parse a word containing some characters  like
"frühe" containing "ü"
"böser" containing "ö"

while i am parsing my xml,which is few different languages, some characters are like the above.
and wen i saw in console, it get interpted,exaactly wen it reacher "ü"
becoz at console it prints "fr"

so can someone provide me some ideas about this thing

regards
shishir

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard `NSXmlParser` class and the XML file has the correct `encoding=` attribute then you shouldn't have anything to worry about. The console output probably isn't unicode-aware so it is interpreting the multi-byte UTF-8 characters literally. Try showing the parsed text in a UIAlertView or some other UI element and see if you still have problems.

Comment: thanks for the reply mike...
yes i am using NSxmlParser,can u tell me,wat should be the correct encoding attribute for my xml???


regards

Comment: It depends on the encoding of the file. <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" /> is probably what you need. But I think NSXMLParser will already assume UTF-8 and parse the text correctly. It's just the that the console isn't handling unicode text properly.

Comment: actually i m working on live xml,so i just saw that xml,
which is having 

"<?xml version="1.0"?>"   this.

here i need to add "encoding="utf-8""  right??


regards

Comment: If you don't control the XML then don't bother. NSXmlParser will probably assume utf-8 by default.

Comment: than how can i overcome this problem.apart from dis special character problem,i cant c any other problem in parsing my xml......
regards

Comment: Try displaying the text in the application's UI rather than through NSLog. I think the reason the character is not being displayed properly is just because the debugger console does not handle unicode properly.